# linux send daily average unique IP to email

Tags: linux, cron

I am running a server and i want to get an email from the server on the peak and average users logged on for a 24hour period. Is this possible with cron and something else?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible.

### What you need:

-a python-script(or perl or something else you like) which make your statistics -> running all the time and see what your server does. You need also the users logged information from your server-information, but this depends on the software you use

-ssmtp -> you can write automatic emails, one more python script which send the email via a system call, this one you hang into your cronjobs

Answer (score 0):

You can see munin type of monitoring system. 
It's very soft, you plugins already in place for a multiple service.

You can set up in easy.
Here is the doc -> **http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/**

Best regard